# Is there a way to increase the upper limit to iCloud storage space?

Tags: icloud

I see [here](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201318) (bold my own):

> With Apple One, you can choose a subscription plan that includes 50GB, 200GB or 2TB of iCloud storage. If you need more iCloud storage, you can buy more for a total of **up to 4TB**.

This seems to mean for people with more than 4TB of data (e.g. someone with lots of family videos, or a hobby photographer), there's simply no way to store it all in iCloud (without creating separate dummy accounts). Is there any way?

For reference, [Google Drive goes up to 30TB](https://one.google.com/storage)

Comment: Thing (A) doesn't do what you want, Thing (B) does do what you want... so why are you insisting on using Thing (A)?  And how are you proposing to back up that much anyway?

Comment: @MarcWilson I think iCloud does a lot of things (e.g. easy integration with native iPhone apps) that other cloud providers won't do? So although other providers can easily provide more space, they don't do the other things iCloud does.

Comment: Two things.  Most importantly, Apple has repeatedly demonstrated near-complete incompetence in services, and so I have little interest in trusting my data to them.  Secondly, I don't find them any better integrated than Google Drive or Dropbox for things not controlled by #1, i.e. I would never keep my contacts, my calendar, my pictures, etc, in Apple services.

Answer (score 3):

Before Apple One introduced 4TB iCloud storage plans, the limit was 2TB. There was no way to increase the limit past that biggest tier, and likewise now with the 4TB tier — there's no tier beyond the largest tier.

This has been a regular complaint of iCloud. The 4TB tier could have been in response to the years of asking for more than 2TB, but of course now we're in the same situation and delaying the inevitable for those of us who store a lot of data in iCloud.